# How would Java GC react to this?

Tags: java, memory-management, memory-leaks, hashmap

I'm working on Java app which is a backend application. That app needs to process certain XML files one by one (SAX, SaxReader from "dom4j"). Processing XML has these steps:

1. Loading an XML file from the disk.
2. Populate HashMap singletons from the database.
3. Process XML file using data from singletons.
4. Clear populated singletons.
5. Sleep 10 seconds before repeating the process.

Hashmap singletons i'm using look like this:

```
public class SomeMap {

    private static SomeMap instance;
    public static SomeMap getInstance() {
        if(instance == null)
            instance = new SomeMap();
        return isntance;
    }

    private HashMap<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>> actualMap;

    private SomeMap() {
        clear();
    }

    public void clear() {
        if(actualMap != null)
            actualMap.clear();
        actualMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<SomeObject>>();
    }

    ...
    //fill method also calls "clear" before populating new values.
    ...

    public SomeObject getSomeObject(String key, String otherCriteria) {
        //for-each loop that obtains specific SomeObject belonging to "key" in the map and having "otherCriteria".
        return foundSomeObject;
    }
}
```

Now, step 3 calls another part of the project which performs certain calculations according to "SomeObject" values in the singletons (singletons are there in order to prevent constant DB lookup as data in singletons is meant just for read).
I need to reload singletons each time because DB parameters may change a bit between processing 2 XML files.

The problem is, i noticed my software takes more and more memory while it's working. Change isn't dramatic, i'm getting about 1 MB per 500 processed files, but since i'll have to process about 40 000 files a day and backend should keep working constantly for days, i'm getting concerned.
Entire software starts with 100 MB of ram usage, after few hours of work it's at about 300.
I can't post entire project as it's huge, but i have a feeling problem might be related to singletons i'm using.

Do you think my singleton design / usage is wrong or memory leak maybe somewhere else in the code?

Comment: I don't think there's a memory leak in the code you posted. GC will kick in when the heap is exhausted and new memory is about to be allocated. You can set your heap to to a small size, say 128Mb with `java -Xmx128m`; it shouldn't reach 300 anymore after a few hours.

Comment: Everything is probably fine. The GC will collect if needed. If it has enough free memory, no problem. But your singleton is a nasty way of reintroducing evil global variables in Java. It makes your code impossible to multi-thread, very hard to test, and promotes spaghetti code. Why don't you just create a new HahMap every time, and pass it as argument to the step3 method?

Comment: @JB Nizet because i can't really know upfront which part of the application will need that data in the future. I guess those hashmaps were created automatically - just like i open DB connection anywhere in the project were i need it, i guessed having global singleton can simulate having data anywhere i need it. After all, i think it's not a problem as data is read-only and for multiple threads i'd use ConcurrentHashMap :)

Comment: Err no, you wouldn't: Thread 1 loads its data to singleton, while thread 2 loads its data... to the same singleton. Consequence: the data is corrupted: it could be thread 1's data, or thread 2's data, or a mix of both, or a part of one (because one thread could clear it while the other fills it). Global state is evil. Pass the map as argument to the methods that need it.

Comment: 1) And what if i put synchronize(this) in clear() and fill()? It will defeat a purpose as singleton will become a bottle neck but would work, right? 2) But then, i would have to drill down and re-pass that map a lot till it gets where it's needed :(

Comment: No, that would still be incorrect: the first thread would fill it, then would start reading values in it, then the second thread would clear it while the first thread still needs to read values in it.